# Accessing my Local Host from different computer in a different network

Tags: xampp, localhost

I'm current using Xammp,and have created a website in the htdocs. I want to know if i can access this from another computer (not in the same network) and work on the site from that other computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the dynamic dns service provided by noip.com. Download the noip client and setup an account in it (try Googling on it).

After that you must edit the conf files in XAMPP to allow outside network to communicate with your network.